# Laravel Nova Value Metric - How to make the decrease a good thing

Tags: laravel-nova

I'd like to add a Metric to a Nova dashboard where an increase in the value is a bad thing.  Meaning, in the picture like below, the arrow would be red instead of green.

[image]

Is this possible to accomplish with a Metric Value?  I thought I had read somewhere had to do this but can't seem to find it now, including in the [Metric docs](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/metrics/defining-metrics.html).